# Sort with Mongoose by the number of respected conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose, aggregate

I want to make a search function with mongoose, and I have to be able to make a research with multiple fields (with Mongoose, in NodeJS).

So, I do something like this :

```
const result = await myModel.find({
   $or [{condition1: "value1"}, {condition2: "value2"}, etc...]
});
```

But, I want to sort the result by the number of condition the object returned have. Like :

If I have 2 conditions, I want to display first the objects respecting the **2 conditions**, then the objects respecting the **1st condition**, and finally the objects respecting the **2nd condition**.

Do you guys know how I can do this? :)

Thanks in advance !

**================EDIT================**

This is the new search function :

```
  /**
   * Search function which returns users matching jobs and skills.
   *
   * @param {Array[String]} jobs
   * @param {Array[String]} skills
   * @return {Array[UserModel]} users
   */
  async search(jobs, skills) {
    // Normalized arrays of jobs, skills and fields (to use it in a mongoose request).
    const jobSkills = [];
    const associatedSkills = [];
    const fields = [];

    for (const job of jobs) {
      jobSkills.push({
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: ["$jobSkills", job],
          },
          2,
          0,
        ],
      });
      fields.push({
        jobSkills: job,
      });
    }

    for (const skill of skills) {
      associatedSkills.push({
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: ["$associatedSkills", skill],
          },
          1,
          0,
        ],
      });
      fields.push({
        associatedSkills: skill,
      });
    }

    // Request to find users matching jobs and skills.
    const users = await UserModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          $or: fields,
        },
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          sortField: {
            $sum: jobSkills.concat(associatedSkills),
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $sort: {
          sortField: -1,
        },
      },
    ]);

    return users;
  }
```

Aggregation Log :

```
Aggregate {
  _pipeline: [
    { '$match': [Object] },
    { '$addFields': [Object] },
    { '$sort': [Object] }
  ],
  _model: Model { User },
  options: {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, a document either matches a query predicate or it doesn't. There isn't really a concept of one document matching "better" than another. So it looks like you'll want to generate a custom value in a new field and sort on that. This will need to be done via an aggregation.

So after the `$match`, we'll want an `$addFields` stage that effectively duplicates the query predicates. For each one it will be wrapped in a conditional statement (`$cond`) where we add `1` for a match or `0` otherwise, e.g.:

```
          {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$condition1",
                  "value1"
                ]
              },
              1,
              0
            ]
          }
```

Then there will be a `$sum` pulling them together to generate the final score to sort on.

Taken together, the aggregation will look something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          condition1: "value1"
        },
        {
          condition2: "value2"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      sortField: {
        "$sum": [
          {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$condition1",
                  "value1"
                ]
              },
              1,
              0
            ]
          },
          {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$condition2",
                  "value2"
                ]
              },
              1,
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "sortField": -1
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/75mh7IrW8TG)

Comment: Thank you for your help, it's seems to work, but I have a little problem :

my "sortField" is equals to 0 everywhere :/

I edited my question with the new function so you can see it :)

Comment: Can you log the generated aggregation so that we can see what it looks like?  Also since the inputs are arrays, you could potentially use `$in` (for both the `$match` and the `$addFields`), but that's probably not strictly necessary

Comment: I edited my post with the aggregation log.
I tried to us ```$in``` but I guess I'm using it bad haha.

Comment: The truncated `Object`s are sort of preventing us from finding out anything helpful

Comment: I think the problem is because I want to check if a string (from a request) is in an array (in db)
Like, I have some tags in DB (```tags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']```) and I want to check if a String is in the array

Comment: I found a solution, I just replaced ```$eq``` by ```$in: [job, "$jobSkills"],```.
Thanks for your help !